# NCAlgebra: is it wrong or do I not understand commuting?

Tags: ncalgebra

Let me try and do a simple non commutative expansion in NCAlgebra:

```
SetNonCommutative[xpt, rp, xq, s]
ExpandNonCommutativeMultiply[xpt*rp*rp*xpt*xq*xpt*rp*s*xq]
```

I get the surprising answer in which some of the symbols do in fact commute

```
s xq ** xq rp ** rp ** rp xpt ** xpt ** xpt
```

I can force these symbols to actually not commute by using `**`:

```
ExpandNonCommutativeMultiply[
 xpt ** rp ** rp ** xpt ** xq ** xpt ** rp ** s ** xq]
```

giving

```
xpt ** rp ** rp ** xpt ** xq ** xpt ** rp ** s ** xq
```

But then what did the `SetNonCommutative` call even do for me? What is its function? I thought it would cause multiplication to be interpreted non-commutatively but perhaps I am missing something and *everything* happens via `**`?

**EDIT**: @DanielHuber in a comment suggests, I think that my confusion here is thinking that `*` is noncommutative multiplication rather than `**`, whcih suggests perhaps that this question is insufficiently clearly stated. `**` is AFAICT non-commutative, non-distributive multiplication even without mathematica. With NCAlgebra it become distributive, non-commutative multiplication. However [the manual seems to suggest](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Encalg/DOCUMENTATION/index.html#to-commute-or-not-to-commute) that one can also get non-commutative multiplication by defining symbols to be non-commutative, which does not work as far as I can see. so *What does `SetNonCommmutative` do? Why do we have it?

Comment: Non commutative multiply is written "**" not "*". Read the manual of NC

Comment: Is your comment formatting as intended, @DanielHuber? It sounds like you want to contrast multiplication using `*`, a single asterisk, and multiplication using an empty string. However my question only uses `**` a double asterisk and `*`, a single asterisk.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, as you rightly guessed,  "**" (two!) is non commutative and "*" is commutative.

Comment: I see that, much like the NCAlgebra manual, sometimes it can take some helpful community feedback to understand the stackexchange manual. If you need to markup code such as asterisks, I recommend [wrapping it in backticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to digest what is going on here.

First, `*` or `blank` is the built in commutative product that you should not mess up with.

So if you want to work with NCAlgebra you need to use `**` for all non-commutative products.

`SetNonCommutative` and `SetCommutative` will then trigger the following behavior:

```
SetNonCommutative[X,Y]
SetCommutative[Z]
X ** Y ** Z
```

will evaluate to

> Z X ** Y

The symbol `Z` is commutative and is pulled out of the noncommutative product. If you dig deeper:

```
FullForm[Z X ** Y]
```

will give you

> Times[Z, NonCommutativeMultiply[X,Y]]

What happened in your example above is the result of a convenience method that is built in NCAlgebra:

```
X^2
```

evaluates to

> X ** X

This way you can work with noncommutative polynomials using powers. The idea is to allow one to type

```
X^8 ** Y^2 ** X^16
```

instead of

```
X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** Y ** Y ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X ** X
```

Note however that you still should use `**` and not `*`! A side effect of this convenience method is that if you type

```
X * X * Y
```

Mathematica will normalize `X * X` into `X^2` which will trigger the NCAlgebra rule to convert the result into

> Y X ** X

While this is a valid Mathematica object, it is not a valid NonCommutative object and some but not all NCAlgebra functions will even warn you about it. For example:

```
NCCollect[X ** X Y, X]
```

will bark that `NCCollect::NotPolynomial: Could not transform expression into nc polynomial`.

I hope this helps.